# Ngrok for local network

Tags: ngrok

Trying to share my local web server with only computers connected to our internal network.

If I run **ngrok http 192.168.10.10:80** it loads and is public.

I thought running it **without http** might work but all i get is an unrecognizable command error.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you don't need to use ngrok while your local web server is connected with the computers in your internal network.

You can access your Web Server via the other computers using its local IP address.